# html5 drag & drop: can't reliably detect user is dragging over an element

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

```js
function handleDragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '0.4';  // this / e.target is the source node.
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
  }

  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

  return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(e) {
  // this / e.target is the current hover target.
  this.classList.add('over');
  console.debug("dragEnterTarget",e.target);
}

function handleDragLeave(e) {
  this.classList.remove('over');  // this / e.target is previous target element.
  console.debug("dragLeaveTarget",e.target);
}

function handleDrop(e) {
  // this / e.target is current target element.

  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
  }

  // See the section on the DataTransfer object.

  return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  // this/e.target is the source node.
  this.style.opacity = '1';
  [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
    col.classList.remove('over');
  });
}

var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .column');
[].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
  col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
  col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
  col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
  col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
});
```

```css
[draggable] {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  /* Required to make elements draggable in old WebKit */
  -khtml-user-drag: element;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}

#columns {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column > * {
  border: solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column.over > * {
  border: solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="columns">
  <div class="column" draggable="true">
    <div>
      A1
    </div>
    <div>
      A2
    </div>
    <div>
      A3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" draggable="true">
    <div>
      B1
    </div>
    <div>
      B2
    </div>
    <div>
      B3
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column" draggable="true">
    <div>
      C1
    </div>
    <div>
      C2
    </div>
    <div>
      C3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm new to drag and drop and followed this tutorial: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

The tutorial works fine, but in it, the drop targets are pretty simple.

What if the drop target is actually a more complex composition of html elements?

I have noticed the 2 following behaviors (at least in recent Chrome):

- dragEnter / dragLeave can also fire for nested html elements, so it seems unreliable to rely only on dragLeave event for knowing that the user is stopping his drag over operation
- dragEnter / dragLeave may not fire for all intermediate nodes in the tree: if you set a onDragEnter on a parent, the first dragEnter event you receive may not have `event.target === parent` (happens for example if the mouse goes directly inside a child when entering the parent), so using event.target for filtering may not be reliable in all cases

Here is a JsFiddle demo using mostly the same structure as the tutorial does, but with a more complex drop target

https://jsfiddle.net/asct3gLj/

as you can see, I'm not able to set the .over class reliably when user is dragging one column on top of another. Can someone find a solution, which does not require changing the html markup?

Comment: As i can understand, you need hover class whenever the drag is triggered?

Comment: yes, i need the .over class like in the demo tutorial, but it should work with a more complex html for the drop target